# how to make webdriver threadsafe in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have searched in Google but did not find a solution. Could someone please help me in it as I am able to find the solution in java but not in C#.

```
private static final ThreadLocal < WebDriver > webDriver = 
    new ThreadLocal < WebDriver > () {
        @Override protected WebDriver initialValue() {
            return BrowserType.getBrowserType().getInstance();
        }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using C# [`ThreadLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx), something like this?

```
public static ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> webDriver =
    new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>(() =>
    {
        return new InternetExplorerDriver();
    });
```

Hopefully you have the correct imports:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
```

Note, I barely code in C#, unless required.

Comment: How does that guarantee thread safety in terms of `Selenium`? Can you please explain?

Comment: The MSDN States: "With the exception of Dispose, all public and protected members of `ThreadLocal<T>` thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads. The value returned for the Value and `IsValueCreated` properties is specific for the thread on which the property is accessed."

Comment: Thanks a lot buhake sindhi, i also implemented the same approach, with your solution it is verified now that it is how we can achieve it.

Comment: @Amit Kapoor if this solution worked for you, please don't forget to accept this answer (tick mark under the score of this answer). :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thread safety of `Selenium` is never guaranteed and strictly speaking it's not thread safe. Please refer to [this](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_Is_WebDriver_thread-safe?)

Comment: Hi Saifur, thanks for your comment but still it is advised to provide one thread to one isntance of webdriver, i can give you a scenario in which supposr if my script does not complete then when my second scriot will start it will create a new instance and that is to be avoided so why not giving a referrence to that thread which i already is in use.

Comment: Can you perform parallel testing without threadsafe, if yes please let me know how.

Answer (score 0):

Java solution:

> Multithreaded client code should use this to assert that it accesses
>   webdriver in a thread-safe manner. Wrap WebDriver instances as
>   follows:

```
WebDriver driver = ThreadGuard.protect(new FirefoxDriver());
```

> Threading issues related to incorrect client threading may have
>   mysterious and hard to diagnose errors. Using this wrapper prevents
>   this category of errors. It is recommended for all multithreaded
>   usage. This class has no overhead of any importance.

[Reference](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ThreadGuard.html)

Comment: Hi Erki, thanks for the comments but i needed to know of there exist a solution in c#

Comment: Erki your solution is good for java, earlier i was using the above mentioned code in java but now i know there is ThreadGuard class, Thank you very much.

Comment: Yea, I know the question was tagged as C#, it for information only.