# How to pass selenium webdriver instance to another class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I browsed through the site but did not find the answer I am looking.

I have

1. Superbase class- here I just create object of a webdriver
2. Baseclass- In this class I extend Superbase class, invoke the driver, and open the URL.
3. Clicklink class- In this class, I again extend the Superbase Class but only to find a null pointer exception. I think I am getting the exception as the driver object is not initialized.

I am just a beginner, and have not tried the browserfactory and other options, as I want to start with simple flow.

Superclass

```
    Public class Superclass
    {
public webdriver Driver;
}
```

Baseclass

```
public class Baseclass extends Superclass
{
setting capabilities and launching the browser
}
```

ClickLink

```
public class Clicklink extends Superclass
{
here I want to click on a link
driver.findelement(by.xpath("xpath").click());
// after this statement I get a null pointer exception
}
```

Can you please guide me here? how can I achieve the same.

Thanks much!

Comment: Show your methods please.

Comment: Is "setting capabilities and launching the browser" in a `@Before*` method or in a constructor?

Comment: Probably by making an object of superclass in child and then invoking it throught it.

    Superclass sl = new Superclass();
    sl.driver.findelement(by.xpath("xpath").click());

Comment: I cant post the methods here, as it is from client machine, however, below is how it looks
In Superclass there are no methods, just a public driver variable
In Baseclass, I have 1 methods, which opens the browser and verifies the title of the page.
In Clicklink class, I have 2 methods
First I create object of Baseclass, and then in Openbrowser method(first method in Clicklink class), I call the method of Baseclass-- this works fine
the problem is in 2nd method in clickClink class, the Submit method, in which I want to use the object from Superclass to click on a link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was setting capabilities using "@Before", and "@Test", but I later removed

Comment: @Kushal, still the same. i.e.null pointer exception

Comment: Have you reviewed any of the page object model tutorials? Many/most of them show how to do this. You can start by reading the Selenium docs on the POM. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern

Comment: @Ashwin - That is beacause you're not initializing the webdriver in constructor of superclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is lot of guesswork done from my side, but please make sure, that your Superclass actually sets the driver and returns it. You can actually make it in both methods:

```
public class Superclass
{
  public WebDriver driver;
  public Superclass(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }
  public WebDriver getdriver(){
    if (driver == null){
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      return driver;
    }else{
      return driver;
    }
  }
}
```

And later in methods you call it by:

```
public class Clicklink extends Superclass
{

getdriver().findelement(by.xpath("xpath").click());

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavel, this helps

Answer (score 4):

`SuperClass` and `BaseClass` are very poor names.  Do not use the language of coding to name your classes use the language of the problem. In this case, web site application testing, use LoginPage, CartPage, ProfilePage, etc.  Use the [Page Object Pattern](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern).

I suggest you use the Factory Pattern to provide the instances of WebDriver for each test. Since all those fit the idea *is a page*, use class extension from a standard PageObject to provide this capability. When navigating, have the current page construct an instance of the new page and pass it the current `webDriver` connection instance. Then any manipulations you apply to that PageObject will be automatically applied to that webDriver instance and its associated browser instance. You should also use a `PageFactory` to provide instances of the pageObject.

```
public abstract class PageObject {
    public WebDriver driver;
    PageObject() {
        // Page can initialise its self
        this.driver = BrowserFactory.webDriver();
    }
    PageObject(final WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.driver = webDriver;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you doesn't want pass driver instance to Page Objects constructor you could create some container class for driver and put it before test and remove it after run. For example:

```
class Driver {
    public static ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> driverInstance = new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>();

    public static IWebDriver GetDriver() {
        return driverInstance.Value;
    }

    public static void SetDriver(IWebDriver driver) {
        driverInstance.Value = driver;
    }
}
```

and make this container field [ThreadLocal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073637/how-to-make-webdriver-threadsafe-in-c) to avoid problems with parallel run.

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a slightly different approach than most on this thread. When I start a test session, I pass the browser name as an argument (i.e. -Dbrowser=chrome) in order to be able to test my web application with different browsers. Then I used the "browser" system property to obtain the browser name when `setup()` is called by my test framework. In my case, I use JUnit annotations in order to JUnit to setup all needed dependencies prior to running any tests.

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() throws Exception {
    // Set up other stuff
    String browser = System.getProperty("browser");
    try {
        SessionDataProvider.driver = TestUtils.createDriver(browser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `createDriver(String)` is a factory method that instantiates the correct driver.

```
public static WebDriver createDriver(String browserName) throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = null;
    try {
        switch(browserName) {
        case "firefox":
            // code to system props and instantiate the driver
            break;
        case "chrome":
            // code to system props and instantiate the driver
            break;
        case "ibrowser":
            // code to system props and instantiate the driver
            break;
        case "edge":
            // code to system props and instantiate the driver
            break;
        case "safari":
            // code to system props and instantiate the driver
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unsupported browser: " + browserName);
        }
    return driver;
}
```

Then, when I execute a step definition, I simply obtain the driver from the data provider class:

```
@And("(I click)/Click on {string}")
public void click(String arg) {

    // Parse String arg and create web element locator...
    try {
        By locator = ...;
        WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(SessionDataProvider.driver, 2)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
        element.click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I did use below code in utility class like below
  public static WebDriver setup(WebDriver driver)
   {
       if(driver == null) {
           driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           return driver;
       }else
          return driver;

         //System.out.println("in method "+ driver.getTitle() );

   }
```

Comment: public class Ebay {
    WebDriver driver=null;


    @Test
    public void testlogic()
    {
        driver=Container.setup(driver);
        driver.get("https://www.ebay.co.uk");

    }

Comment: Why are you passing a driver instance into a method that is supposed to be creating the driver instance???